# INDEX & MATCH Two Lookup Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please Help me..

I was create formula that index matching meet 2 criteria.
but, its result is not same like I used to do with 1 criteria.
btw, the condition of criteria 2 is by column but the criteria range is by row.

Here the code below:

```
=IF(OR(IF(ISNA(INDEX($L$17:$L$30,MATCH(LEFT($B6,4),$C$17:$C$30,0),MATCH(C$5,$G$17:$G$30,0))),"",INDEX($L$17:$L$30,MATCH(LEFT($B6,4),$C$17:$C$30,0),MATCH(C$5,$G$17:$G$30,0)))="",IF(ISNA(INDEX($L$17:$L$30,MATCH(LEFT($B6,4),$C$17:$C$30,0),MATCH(C$5,$G$17:$G$30,0))),"",INDEX($L$17:$L$30,MATCH(LEFT($B6,4),$C$17:$C$30,0),MATCH(C$5,$G$17:$G$30,0)))="1.xxxx"),"Not Done","Done")
```

thank you for the support..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use in C6:

`{=INDEX($L$17:$L$30,MATCH(LEFT($B6,4)&C$5,$C$17:$C$30&$G$17:$G$30,0))}`

Don't enter the Brackets `{}` this indicates, that it is an array formula. You have to enter the Formula with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`.

Comment: **Note:** Just wanted to give a small headsup that concatenating multiple search values is a very error prone and unreliable method. The more common way would be to build a simple boolean structure.